# Correct use of verbs

Tags: modal-verbs

> **Anyone who would speak** with authority on the poets of the Renaissance must have a broad aquaintance with the writers of classical antiquity.

Here, I think there should be "Anyone who will speak" at the place of "Anyone who would speak". But I don't know either first one is wrong or right. Please explain.

Comment: They're both fine, although the second version is actually more unusual than the first. The only context I can picture in my head for it is somebody holding a gun to a group of picture and shouting that statement. This is mostly because of the combination of **will** and **must**, not only because of the verb itself. If it were **will** and **should** it would be more natural. In fact, if **must** is changed to **should**, then I think the second version becomes the more natural.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's fine. It's a rather old-fashioned use of *would* to mean *wants to* or *wishes to*.

Comment: I'm not sure about "old-fashioned" there. It's certainly not true that OP's suggested replacement of ***would*** by ***will*** would be more "modern" - it's just *relatively unlikely*. And I might be mistaken, but I have the distinct feeling that to the extent there *has* been a usage shift over time, it was probably more common to use ***will*** in this exact context 2-3 centuries ago than it is today. I'd also just point out that *I couldn't marry anyone who **would** do that!* is perfectly natural English, but probably only a non-native speaker would use ***will*** there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I certainly don't suggest that _will_ would be more modern there. I think the use of _would_ that I identified does not function as a past of _will_, but is isolated. I think it is different from the _anyone who would do that_ construction, which I think **is** the past of _will_ (past for irrealis, so-called "past subjunctive"). The original sentence is not irrealis.

Comment: Ah, right - I see what you mean. I now agree with you, but I'll leave my first comment there unless / until a mod deletes it.